# Average relative to quantity

Tags: average

Not really sure how to ask my question. I have a list of average transaction wait times which are averaged over the count of the transactions for each zone, as shown in the list below which is sorted by the avg wait highest to lowest. When I look at the top entry I think "yuck, they waited 177 seconds and it was only 1293 transactions." When I look at the entry for zone:22 I think "wooHoo! This zone had 2600 transactions and only waited 47 seconds!"

I want to give each row a score based on the number of transactions and the wait time that they experienced. What would be the bast way to do that? (I'm sure I learned how to do this 40 years ago when I was in High School, but I don't remember today what formula to apply. ;-) ) Maybe I'm overthinking this??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has many answers. It depends on what is important. I can give a score as number of transactions plus number of seconds wait time, but that is probably not what you want. I would suggest giving separate scores for wait time and number of transactions (how you score these is also subjective), then take an average (or some weighted average) of the scores. Here is an example:

- Score for transactions is #of transactions/2609 *100, where 2609 is the maximum number of transactions in a zone
- Score for wait times is 100*28.6/wait time, where 28.6 is the minimum wait time
- Weighted score is (2*Wait time score+transactions score)/3

Comment: Ok, so you're basing the scores on the maximum number of transactions and the minimum wait time. I like this. I'm a little confused with your weighted score. Can you explain that a little bit more, please?

Comment: It's an example to show that I value more shorter wait times than number of transactions, in this case twice as much. If I value them equally, then the score would be just the average of the two.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that explanation. I can now take these ideas and play with them. Yes we value shorter wait times, but also need to consider busyness. What you provided will give me a good starting point.